# Php cart array check if item is already added

Tags: php, arrays, cart

I'm trying to develop a e-commerce application with a shopping cart using mostly php and jquery.

I need to compare a selected item (id, sku, size, and color) to items already in an array. If the item already exists in the array, then increase the amount by the amount of the chosen item.

Meaning:

1. Client clicks on an item "add to cart"
2. Client clicks the item again
3. PHP function checks if the newly added item exists in array, if it exists increase amount, if not push into array

Comment: And what's the exact problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please add more description including code for cart.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write code something like this.

```
$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];

/*
 * If product already exist into the cart then update QTY of product
 * Othewise add new product into the cart
 */
if(isset($cart[$product['id']])):
    $cart[$product['id']]['qty'] += 1;
else:
    $cart[$product['id']] = $product;
    $cart[$product['id']]['qty'] = 1;
endif;

$_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
```